# Pages categorized by post

Tags: wordpress

I got 4 categories in Wordpress, let say categories C1, C2, C3, C4. So I make posts and assign either one of the categories to these posts. Then I made the categories a menu in my primary menu, the purpose of which is when the user click C1 all posts under that category is shown, same goes for the rest of the menu items. How do I make this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a template to display posts according to category and use that template for pages that will display posts and then use those pages  as menu.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin when you add the category to the menu, it is a built in function.  Go to appearance -> menu -> category  choose the one you want, add to menu save menu.  The template that outputs for those pages is archive.php
Documentation found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index)

Example on a site [category training plans](http://runfatgirl.com/category/training-plans/)